# Вытащить из списка каждый путь каждого файла в одну строку

Tags: c#

Можно ли сделать так чтобы из списка выбрать определённый путь к нужному файлу `List<string>`?

```
public static List<string> GameFiles()
{
  var retList = new List<string>();
  retList.Add(Path.Combine(AppData, "Games", "Account Base"));
  retList.Add(Path.Combine(LocalAppData, "Games", "Account Base"));
  retList.Add(Path.Combine(AppData, "Games", "Connect"));
  retList.Add(Path.Combine(LocalAppData, "Games", "Connect"));
  return retList;
}
```

В цикле прохожусь по списку

```
foreach (string pair in GameFiles())
{
   Console.WriteLine(pair); // Тут выводит все списки. 
}
```

А мне нужно чтобы выводило так же как через foreach только в одну строку, такой способ возвращает только первые элементы из списка и дальше не идёт:

```
string Acc = GameFiles().First(x => Path.GetFileName(x) == "Account Base");
string Conn= GameFiles().First(x => Path.GetFileName(x) == "Connect");
```

Как сделать чтобы `Acc` возвращал список всех файлов с `Account Base` в одну строку? И аналогично с `Conn` Если это возможно конечно)

Comment: Вы можете изменить [TextWriter.NewLine](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-Ru/dotnet/api/system.io.textwriter.newline?view=netframework-4.8) на что-либо другое, например на пробел. Тогда [Console.WriteLine](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-Ru/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?view=netframework-4.8) не будет переводить на новую строку в конце.

Comment: @МаксимФисман, это вообще не то что мне нужно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```cs
string Acc = string.Join(" ", GameFiles().Where(x => Path.GetFileName(x) == "Account Base"));
```

Кстати, ваш метод получения списка выглядит странно. Странность заключается в том, что он пересоздает список каждый раз с нуля, когда вы к нему обращаетесь. Если вы создаете список каждый раз из одних и тех же данных, лучше его закешировать, а вместо метода вообще лучше использовать свойство.

А метод создания списка вынести отдельно.

```cs
private static List<string> _gameFiles;

public static List<string> GameFiles => _gameFiles ??= BuildGameFiles();

private static List<string> BuildGameFiles()
{
    var retList = new List<string>();
    retList.Add(Path.Combine(AppData, "Games", "Account Base"));
    retList.Add(Path.Combine(LocalAppData, "Games", "Account Base"));
    retList.Add(Path.Combine(AppData, "Games", "Connect"));
    retList.Add(Path.Combine(LocalAppData, "Games", "Connect"));
    return retList;
}
```

Тогда вышеупомянутая строка будет выглядеть так

```cs
string Acc = string.Join(" ", GameFiles.Where(x => Path.GetFileName(x) == "Account Base"));
```

Теперь список будет построен только когда вы впервые обратились к свойству `GameFiles`, а все последующие разы будет переиспользоваться уже готовый.

Comment: Ваааа, сработало, спасибо!!!

Comment: @ZidoX дополнил ответ весьма важной информацией.

Comment: спасибо! А свойства использовать потому что `return` ?

Comment: @ZidoX не знаю, как связан ретурн со свойствами, но вы лучше прочитайте про свойства, чем они отличаются от полей, методов и т.д. В данном конкретном случае потому что так удобнее.